# How to make simple dynamic dropdown in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, ajax, dropdown, laravel-5.4

I tried to learn through the tutorials, but most of them didn't include examples, some of them hard to understand etc etc.

I copied all the codes from [this website](http://www.jmkleger.com/post/ajax-crud-for-laravel-5-4), but I don't know how to put simple dynamic dropdown selection just like this pic :

[image]

My dropdown database goes like this

demo_state

**id, name, created_at, updated_at**

demo_city

**id,state_id, name, created_at, updated_at**